# MAMP Pro hosts not working

Tags: mysql, apache, hosts, mamp-pro

Since I'm a fan of MAMP I bought a Pro license today. I have followed [this MAMP.tv tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f23yZ_EgC0I&index=5&list=PLXlVJXqzkgyr8BTemfF_uoEGqbRDs8O5w) about adding a host, which looks very simple and straightforward.

Although it isn't so easy for my. As you can see in the screenshot I did add some custom hosts. One is the `mamp.mvoc.nl` and it is added just as in the tutorial. But when I visited this url I got an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error. The basic htdocs folder on `localhost:8888` is working and showing the default MAMP page. When I visit `mamp.mvoc.nl:8888` I got redirected to `localhost:8888`. All port settings for MySQL and Apache are default.

When I view my hosts file in `/etc/hosts` I see those MAMP lines:

`127.0.0.1       mamp.mvoc.nl    # MAMP PRO - Do NOT remove this entry!
::1             mamp.mvoc.nl    # MAMP PRO - Do NOT remove this entry!`

So this looks good I guess??
I got no firewall on my laptop and I'm using a Macbook Pro with OSx Sierra.

Anyone knows what's wrong?

[image: MAMP Pro custom host]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue before, I changed the ports (on the left menu) to 80, 81, 443, 7443, 3306 & 11211 (there's a button for that) and that worked for me.

I added an [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrBUf.png) here so you can guide better.

Let us know if that solved the problem